# Json Structure for compound keys

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

[I'm trying to implements this solution:](https://hellokoding.com/content/images/2015/11/many-to-many-extracolumns.png)
BookPublisher has a compound key, so i built embeddable class:

```
    @Embeddable
    public class BookPublisherID implements Serializable{

        private int bookID;
        private int publisherID;
//getters and constructor
```

This is bookPublisher class:

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "book_publisher")
    public class BookPublisher implements Serializable{

        @EmbeddedId
        private BookPublisherID id;
        private Date publishedDate;

        @MapsId("bookID")
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
        private Book book;
        @MapsId("publisherID")
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
        private Publisher publisher;
//getters and setters
```

This is book class:

```
 @Entity
    public class Book{
        private int id;
        private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers;
 //getters and setters
```

Publisher Class:

```
    @Entity
        public class Publisher{
            private int id;
            private String name;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
            private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers;
 //getters and setters
```

BookPublisher repository:

```
public interface BookPublisherRepository extends JpaRepository<BookPublisher, BookPublisherID>{}
```

And this is Implementation:

```
@Service
public class BookPublisherImpl implements BookPublisherMetier{


    @Autowired
    private BookPublisherRepository bookPublisherRepository;

    @Override
    public BookPublisher savePublication(BookPublisher bookPublisher) {
                bookPublisher.setPublishedDate(new Date());
        return bookPublisherRepository.save(bookPublisher);
    }

}
```

The problem is how to add a bookPublisher in Json in the case of compound key(i work with postman). I tried the solution below and other possibility but i got the same problem: 
attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.entities.BookPublisher.book]

```
{  
        "id": {
            "bookID":1,
            "publisherID":1
        },
        "book":{
            "id":1
        },
        "publisher":{
            "id":1
      } 
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of key items here.

1. If all you're doing with the objects is basic getter and setter, you should just use default properties rather than defining the private fields.  I've found that this will always serialize even without having to implement serializable myself.  Also, realize that private variables will not serialize since they're not accessible.
2. You'll need to use custom holder objects instead of using the entity objects.  You need to pick a base object and a direction for the relationships.  Entity objects include a relationship back to the related object you come from, making a circular reference that can't serialize.  It would just go infinitely between them.  You'll need to use an object structure that doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks Verito, but i'm soryy i didn't understand you !